# What's the correct way to download a pdf attachment from a GET request in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this simple view:

```
class Reports(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        report_id = request.GET.get("report_id")
        response = get_report(report_id)
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The get_report method simply strips the payload and returns just an id that needs to be sent to GET the pdf.

Get_report

```
def get_report(path):
    head = get_header()
    payload = {}
    path = "https://fakepath.com"
    response = requests.get(path, json=payload, headers=head, stream=True)
    return response
```

I get a 200 OK which shows that the request was successful but how do I get the pdf file to download. The endpoint returns a pdf.

The server response headers:

```
 access-control-allow-origin: * 
 access-control-expose-headers: content-disposition 
 content-disposition: attachment; filename="assessment_hbx0MkrjYad2I2suaKcrIdzOcaMlIBSGDw4I8TBprWC28GbDFkF0KxuBpNMB1qYc.pdf" 
 content-length: 48818 
 content-type: application/octet-stream 
 date: Wed,20 Apr 2022 19:16:34 GMT 
 server: istio-envoy 
 x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 2099 
 x-powered-by: Express
```

Filename is unique for each download so it changes all the time in the servers response.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the data of your endpoint:

```py
bytes = b64decode(pdf_data, validate=True)
pdf_file = open("your_file_name + '.pdf', 'wb')

pdf_file.write(bytes)
pdf_file.close()
```

Now you have the pdf saved in Django somewhere.
Then you can write a view to download the file, this view ends with:

```py
return HttpResponse(pdf_data, content_type="application/pdf")
```

Comment: You mean this in the method?
```def get_report(path):
    head = get_header()
    payload = {}
    path = "https://fakepath.com"
    response = requests.get(path, json=payload, headers=head, stream=True)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/pdf")
```

Comment: yes but the pdffile.name has to be in respons

Comment: But I do not know what the incoming filename will be as it is dynamic (changes every time). Is this a name to save the file as on my side or the name of the incoming file? Thanks

Comment: .name is not the pdf file name, see my edited answer. You have to create the pdf file from the data of your endpoint i guess.